# process.env is an empty object

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp, browserify

I am using Gulp / Browserify / Node on Windows, and I want to only include debugging information when in development.

I have a dependant task that is being run before anything else

```
gulp.task('set-dev-node-env', function() {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'
}
```

Yet when I try and access this in my code I am finding process.env is an empty object.

```
console.log("process.env",process.env)
```

[image]

How can I get this to work?

Comment: use `gulp-util`, read more about it [here](http://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2015/10/13/gulp-gulpfile-environment-variable/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution was to use [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify)

```
var envify = require('envify/custom')
```

and add it as a transform on my browserify() call

```
.transform(envify({
                NODE_ENV: 'development'
            }))
```